# When I try to route I got error in Browser console not in the vs code terminal

Tags: reactjs

**
When I try to route I got this error

(Uncaught Error: [Products] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>)
The code is below
**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart} />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/cart">
            <Cart cart={cart} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

**Products component**

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

import Product from './Product/Product';
import useStyles from './styles';


const Products = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Grid container justifyContent="center" spacing={4}>
            {products.map((product) => (
                <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                    <Product product={product} onAddToCart = {onAddToCart} />
                </Grid>
            ))}
        </Grid>
    </main>
    );
   
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: Can you show you `Products` component ?

Comment: I have added the products component.